# Manipulating with datagridview and dropdownlist

Tags: c#, winforms

here is the image of my form.

this should be done like this.
1. The user will select the item to be renamed. (ex. user select "string1")
2. Select new item name on the dropdown.(ex. user choose "new string 1")
**note: the selected item on the dropdown will be the new name of "string1"**

3. Click on the button.(**upon clicking the button. this will automatically create the changes that has been made**).

[image]

here is the problem: 
how can i change the item name on the datagridview from the selected item on the dropdown?

here is some of my codes.

```
public void loadgrid()
        {
            DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn checkboxColumn = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
            checkboxColumn.Width = 25;
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(checkboxColumn);

            DataGridViewTextBoxColumn textboxcolumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            textboxcolumn.Width = 150;
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(textboxcolumn);

            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[] { false, "string1" });
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[] { false, "string2" });
        }
```

for button1

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int x = 0;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            { 
                DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)row.Cells[0];
                chk.TrueValue = true;
                if(chk.Value == chk.TrueValue) // there no chk.Check on datagridview just chk.Selected
                {
                    //code here
                    //this will test if the checkbox has been checked.
                    //the selected item on the dropdown will be the
                    //new name of the item on the datagridview
                }
            }
                x = x + 1;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help if you want to change all the strings in rows with checked checkBox:

```
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    if (!row.IsNewRow)
                    {
                        DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk1 = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)row.Cells[0];
                        if (chk1 != null && chk1.Value!=null && (bool)chk1.Value) // there no chk.Check on datagridview just chk.Selected
                        {
                            string newString = string.Empty;
                            if (comboBox1.SelectedItem != null)
                            {
                                newString = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
                                row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1].Value = newString;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

And if you want to change the string only in a selected row where the CheckBox is checked then you can use this code:

```
                if(dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count>0)
                {
                    DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0];
                    if (!row.IsNewRow)
                    {
                        DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk1 = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)row.Cells[0];
                        if (chk1 != null && chk1.Value!=null && (bool)chk1.Value) // there no chk.Check on datagridview just chk.Selected
                        {
                            string newString = string.Empty;
                            if (comboBox1.SelectedItem != null)
                            {
                                newString = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
                                row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1].Value = newString;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

and if you want to set all selected rows (if this is possible in your `DataGridView` control, then just iterate `SelectedRows` property

Comment: I checked the code before posting and it was working fine. Where exactly is your error?

Comment: there is error on (bool) - Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: i also tried this one. bool b = true; then change the (bool) to (b)chk1.value but still there's error.

Comment: check it now, I changed the code but I think that you are calling this method before you insert anything into the DataGridView.